# How to use new automatic react runtime import with @mdx-js/loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using MDX with React's new [JSX Transform](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html). My babel configuration is following:

```
const plugins = [
  ['@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator'],
  ['@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'],
  ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx', {
    runtime: 'automatic',
    importSource: 'react'
  }]
];
```

However when bundling and transpiling MDX files via Webpack using `@mdx-js/loader`, I get following error:

```
importSource cannot be set when runtime is classic.
```

It looks like it is not picking runtime as `automatic` from the `Babel` configuration. How can I tell the loader to pick import source as mentioned in the babel config file.

Comment: I believe `mdx` 1.x doesn't support the new JSX transform yet as per https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/pull/1307.

Comment: @chenxsan is there a workaround that you know of?

Comment: @chenxsan so does that mean the runtime falls back to classic?

Comment: @istrupin Yes, it does falls back.